# Libgdx Issues managing a single Clicklistener

Tags: java, android, libgdx, listener

In Libgdx, I'm attempting to set a Clicklistener to a specific circumstance when a specific button is pressed.

```
public void setExamine(final ClickListener cl) {
        examine.addListener(cl);
}
```

This is code I have from within a class which can be accessed from another class by doing:

```
table.setExamine(new ClickListener(){...});
```

however, doing so means that it will add a new ClickListener every time.

Instead of having this occur, is there any way to have it manage a single click listener instead of adding one? I've tried using

```
public void setExamine(final ClickListener cl) {
            examine.clearListeners();
            examine.addListener(cl);
}
```

but it seems to completely remove any functionality of the button clicking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hold the reference of "cl" which you are passing to setExamine method in your class. Then you can remove this specific listener first in your setExamine method. I assume that examine is a scene2d actor.

```
private ClickListener clickListener;

public void setExamine(final ClickListener cl) {
   if(clickListener != null) {
      examine.removeListener(clickListener);
   }
   examine.addListener(cl);
   clickListener = cl;
}
```

If you want to apply a solution like clearListeners(), you should keep default listener of the button.

```
while(examine.getListeners().size > 1) {
   examine.removeListener(examine.getListeners()[1]);
}
```